# Amazon AWS Load balancer with shared director for web application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I would like to know something about hosting my Laminas project on Amazon AWS.
I would like to start deploying it on two web servers with one load balancer. So I have to define the /var/www/html directory on each web servers.

My question is, what about if I would like to create somewhere (like S3; Jump server or something else) only one directory where I could put my web application files and make my web servers pointing on this folder (Symblinks for instance ?).
Is that possible ? and how can I achieve it ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be clear, if you use S3, you won't need Load Balancer.

In case you want to host on EC2, you can use EFS or install nfs on your jump server and make your web servers mount that nfs.

Comment: Why will he need a jump server? Two EC2s with one load balancer and a shared efs will do it.

Comment: As I read, I think maybe he already has a jump server so nfs will optimize the cost

Comment: Thank you @AshBlake, thank you very much. To Riz, I do not want my web servers be access directly via SSH, but only authorise my Jump server to connect to them

Comment: Thanks Samuel, if my answer can help you, please give it an accept and raise a useful vote